# How to display Values from a multiselect listbox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a form in Excel macro. This form will capture the values inserted in textboxes, listbox and store in Sheet2.

There are 2 buttons in the form applet named "Next" and "Previous".  These button will be used for navigating between the saved records.  I am able to navigate between records and the values display fine in textboxes.  However, I am not sure how can I display the Values from listboxes.  My list box is a multiselect list box.

I have provided snippet of my code on how the records are saved in sheet2 and how the navigation happens when clicked on Next button.

```
     Private Sub Save_Click()

      Dim ctl As Control
      Dim S As String
      Dim i As Integer


      RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
     With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.Name1.Value  ' capture value from list box

     'below code is for capturing value from multiselect listbox 
     With AOI
      For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
         If .Selected(i) = True Then S = S & ", " & .List(i)
     Next i
      Range("A1").Offset(RowCount, 10).Value = S
     End With
    End Sub
```

Below code is for navigating between saved records..

```
   Private Sub Next1_Click()

      strCurrentSetofRows = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
      i = i + 1: j = 0

      If i > (strCurrentSetofRows - 1) Then
        MsgBox "No More Records"
      Exit Sub
      End If

      Set sRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

      Name1.Text = sRange.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
   End Sub
```

Any thoughts on how can I display saved values of AOI (my field).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are storing the values using `,` as a separator, you can use the same to split the values and upload it to the `ListBox`. BTW, I hope you are generating the `ListBox` with the complete list in the `UserForm's` ***Initialize*** event?

Here is a very basic example. Please amend it to suit your needs.

Let's say Cell `A1` has `Blah1,Blah2,Blah6`. Then try this code

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Long, j As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti

    For i = 1 To 10
        ListBox1.AddItem "Blah" & i
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ArValues As Variant
    Dim sValue As String
    Dim multivalues As Boolean

    If InStr(1, Range("A1").Value, ",") Then
        ArValues = Split(Range("A1").Value, ",")
        multivalues = True
    Else
        sValue = Range("A1").Value
        multivalues = False
    End If

    If multivalues = True Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(ArValues)
            For j = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
                If ListBox1.List(j) = ArValues(i) Then
                    ListBox1.Selected(j) = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    Else
        For j = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            If ListBox1.List(j) = sValue Then
                ListBox1.Selected(j) = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Though this code reads the values however it seems to populating wrong field.  The values are getting populated in combobox which is one above the listbox. Secondly the values of my listbox are on the 11th column in sheet2.  I am not generating the ListBox with the complete list in the UserForm's Initialize event.  The values in Listbox are configured as Name manager and in the listbox rowsource property I have specified the name manager. Do i still need to initialize it?  how does it help?

Comment: umm strange I must have missed your comment. Is your listbox not getting generated in the Userform's Initialize event?

Comment: do you mean the values? the values are static values which are defined in sheet3 as name manager.  The values seem to be populating in a free text box rather than checking the list box.

Comment: I managed to make it work... the arrays were creating some mis-match.  It works now.